# An exception occurred while populating the properties for the Print Queue object. Win32 error: The printer name is invalid

Tags: node.js, asp.net, .net, angular, electron

`System.Printing.PrintQueueException: An exception occurred while populating the properties for the PrintQueue object. Win32 error: The printer name is invalid.`

The code is working fine in Windows 7, when I run the same code in Windows 10 it's showing this error. What can I try next?

Answer (score 0):

It's Windows permissions related. A group policy would be my guess.  I can't be more specific than this as I'm a software developer, not a IT security guru.

Ran into this error for the first time in 4 years at current position, and happens for us when asking for the Default Printer using this VB.NET code snippet:

```
    Dim printServer As New System.Printing.LocalPrintServer()
    Def_DriverName = printServer.DefaultPrintQueue.FullName
```

Issue won't present itself under administrator privileges.